# Text and dates in same table. Order so that text is always on bottom

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a table with dates, in the same table I also have text entries. Example:

```
2014-11-02
2014-11-01
Not done
2014-10-05
Not done
Not done
```

If I run SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dates then I get

```
2014-10-05
2014-11-01
2014-11-02
Not done
Not done
Not done
```

which is perfect. But when I reverse this query using desc I get:

```
Not done
Not done
Not done
2014-11-02
2014-11-01
2014-10-05
```

What I would like is for "Not done" to always be on the bottom. If anyone got a clue :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple way to do what you want:

```
order by (left(dates, 4) + 0 > 0) desc,
         dates
```

It converts the first four digits to a number.  If the number is greater than zero, then it assumes that it is a year and puts those rows first.  This doesn't check for a fully formed date, but it is probably sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table order by (left(mydates, 4) + 0 > 0) desc, mydates doesn't work. It does put the "not yet" on bottom but it also lists the oldest date entries on top, when it should be the newest. e.g 2014-11-02 2014-11-01 etc. Whereas 2014-10-05 is listed first

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(dates,'Not done') ASC, dates ASC
```

And after your comment:

```
SELECT dates, dateadded, (dates='Not yet') AS test, IF(test, cast(`dateadded` AS char), cast(`dates` AS char)) AS testsort FROM table ORDER BY test ASC, testsort ASC
```

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD(mydates,'Not yet') asc, mydates desc does produce the result I wanted. BUT, it does list the most recent "Not yet" at the bottom of the list, while I would like the most recent ones at the top (just beneath the last date) and the oldest ones at the bottom? I would like to sort using "entry added" dates

Comment: mydates and dateadded. So I sort mydates using the techniques you described. Then sort the "Not yet" fields only using dateadded to place the most recent "Not yet" beneath the last mydates entry. And the oldest "Not yet" at the bottom of the list.. If it makes sense.. Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't know if it's ok like that... (or if we need to change sort order)